# Синхронизация календаря с Exchange и внешней API

Tags: java, exchange

Нужно синхронизировать удаление события в Exchange  с внешней системой. Если я удалю событие в Exchange, оно переместится в папку удаленные почты. А после восстановления, событие добавляется в календарь с новым id. Внешняя система видит данное событие как новое. Как через API синхронизировать события?